Java Apache Beam, mock external Clients initialized in @Setup method of DoFn with Constructors variables
Apache Beam recommends to use Fakes instead of Mocks, since Mocks cannot serialize over the pipeline.
I am writing unit tests for older code, where the class is using Apache Beam calling other external class services (which I have not written or cannot change). * The serviceApi isn't using interface, however can wrap in one if needed.
public class DataAdapter extends DoFn<KV<String, Product>, Void>{
    public String processCategory;
    public Map<String, String> configs;
    public transient ServiceApi serviceApi; 
    
    public DataAdapter(String processCategory, Map<String, String> configs) {
        this.processCategory = processCategory;
        this.configs = configs;
    }
  
    @Setup
    public void init() {
        serviceApi = new ServiceApi(processCategory, configs);
    }

    @ProcessElement
    public void processData(ProcessContext context, @Element KV<String, Product> input) {
        try {
            String productId = input.getKey();
            serviceApi.getData();
            ....
     }
} 

Attempt:
I created the fake below. Calling the constructors with nulls will cause Argument Exception errors in the serviceApi constructor. So I tried a factory create pattern which is probably not ideal. (trying to find another solution)
However, the fake keeps getting overriden, since for each ProcessElement, it calls Setup, with reinitializes Parent Class. We had to initialize in each SetupBatch, since serviceApi was not serializable in running Apache Beam application.
Create Fake:
public class ServiceApiFake extends ServiceApi {

    public ServiceApiFake() {
        super(null, null);
    }

    public static ServiceApiFake create() {
        try {
            return new ServiceApiFake();
        } catch (Exception ignore) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public DataItem getData(String keyId) {
        return null;
    }
}

Test:
TestStream<KV<String, Product>> testStream = TestStream.create(KvCoder.of(StringUtf8Coder.of(), SerializableCoder.of(Product.class)))
            .addElements(KV.of("25", product)).advanceWatermarkToInfinity();

DataAdapter dataAdapter = new DataAdapter("productCategory", configs);
dataAdapter.serviceApi = new ServiceApiFake();
pipeline.apply(testStream).apply(ParDo.of(dataAdapter));
pipeline.run();


Error in test run: ArgumentExceptionError at Setup init, since it
return to calling the regular service at Setup instead of fake.

I thought about going back to testing methods individually by calling "processData" Method, without calling setup, and using a mockito Mock on ProcessContext, ElementInput, and serviceApi when(serviceApi.getData()).thenReturn(..) . This strategy actually works, its not ideal, but allows me to test in some degree. Note the Api is transient property,  as application will error if not. The serviceApi isn't using interface, however can wrap in one if needed. This is older project, and doesn't use Spring Boot or GoogleGuice injector.
I wish Apache Beam team had a better, robust alternative in using fakes, or allow mocks somehow. Or allow DoFnTester again (since its currently deprecated). Company policy does not allow deprecated usage anymore.
Resource: I looked at referring stackoverflow article. Their serviceAPI doesn't have constructor variables, or argument exception validators within the serviceAPI, so it works in their situation. Also it uses VisibleForTesting Annotation, not recommended in our company codebase.
Apache Beam , mock external Clients initialized in @Setup Lifecycle method of DoFn

there are 2 key conditions on using fakes when initializing your service in Setup method:

adding setting method to your DoFn
initialization in setup method only if service is null.

@VisibleForTesting is just an annotation indicating that method is used only in tests. you can replace with a comment or java doc.

if you are unable to modify existing DataAdapter then it will be difficult to write unit tests since as is DataAdapter is tightly coupled with ServiceApi.

The solution I've used in the past is: don't initialize in @SetUp. Use standard interface dependency injection into the constructor, and pass in the real ones for your real pipelines and the fake ones for your tests.
You can further abstract this away from users of your transform by providing a helper static method for non-testing purposes:
static PTransform<PCollection<? extends InputT>, PCollection<Void>> create(String processCategory, Map<String, String> configs) {
  return ParDo.of(new DataAdapter(new ServiceApi(processCategory, configs)));
}


All of this references your example above.

can you provide robust explanation , showing DI and injection, thanks,
